# string_agg is to slow with big data and i need a faster solution

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with contacting a string from a result and it is taking to long to execute
this is the solution I have:

```
declare @damagedParties table (caseid varchar(max),FirstName varchar(max),LastName varchar(max),damagedName varchar(max))

insert @damagedParties
select t.caseid,ped.FirstName as FirstName,ped.LastName,concat(ped.FirstName,' ',ped.LastName) as damagedName
from [Case] t
inner join [KCC].[dbo].[Party] p1 on p1.CaseId = t.caseid 
LEFT JOIN Person ped ON ped.PersonOrBusinessId = ped.PersonOrBusinessId and p1.PartyTypeRefData = 'kpcparty$PARTY_INJUREDPARTY_F'

select string_agg(d.damagedName,', ')
from @damagedParties d
group by d.caseid
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: I am using an SQL server

Comment: How many rows in @damagedParties? Which part of query is slow - inserting into @damagedParties or string aggregating?

Comment: every table is big and the string_agg is slowing the query execution

Comment: Try using For Xml Path clause, my friend.

Comment: You have two queries.  How do you know it is the string agg causing the problem?  How much data do you have?  What is "to [sic] long"?

Answer (score 0):

The LEFT JOIN condition in the first query joins the Person table to itself on PersonOrBusinessId.  Presumably, the JOIN should be from Person table to the Party table?  Something like this

```
insert @damagedParties
select t.caseid, ped.FirstName, ped.LastName,
       concat(ped.FirstName,' ',ped.LastName) as damagedName
from [Case] t
     join [KCC].[dbo].[Party] p1 on p1.CaseId = t.caseid 
     left join Person ped ON p1.PersonOrBusinessId = ped.PersonOrBusinessId
where p1.PartyTypeRefData = 'kpcparty$PARTY_INJUREDPARTY_F';
```